# Mapbox uploads api is not returning tileset id

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, mapbox, aws-sdk, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to upload a file to Mapbox studio via [uploads API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/uploads/)
I have followed all the steps, but it's not returning desired results, instead, it's returning this

[image]

Here is my code. Please help.

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
import fs from "fs";
import Uploads from "@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/uploads.js";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";

const uploadsClient = new Uploads({
  accessToken:"MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN",
  mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
});

const getCredentials = async () => {
  return await uploadsClient
    .createUploadCredentials()
    .send()
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("log ", response.body);
      return response.body;
    });
};

const putFileOnS3 = (credentials) => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: credentials.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: credentials.secretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: credentials.sessionToken,
    region: "us-east-1",
  });
  return s3.putObject(
    {
      Bucket: credentials.bucket,
      Key: credentials.key,
      Body: fs.createReadStream("book1.jpg"),
    },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("fole uploaded success fully", data);
      }
    }
  );
};

getCredentials().then(putFileOnS3);
```

As per the docs it should return this response :

```
{
  "complete": false,
  "tileset": "example.markers",
  "error": null,
  "id": "hij456",
  "name": "example-markers",
  "modified": "{timestamp}",
  "created": "{timestamp}",
  "owner": "{username}",
  "progress": 0
}
```

but my response is

```
{
  ETag: '"3ed1b49aa52ba769138b7770b38cfa6f"',
  ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256',
  VersionId: 'omlUQOXPS77CJo.c8n4h2.LT.nYKblCL'
}
```